# How to get rid of a complex object while using react

Tags: json, reactjs

I received form the db the following `object` (or whatever it is):

```
[
  {"regions": 
    {"_id":null,"_labels":null,"name":"Lazio","uuid":"ca1c1021-92f4-412b-aa3d-6c997cba248e"}},
  {"regions": 
    {"_id":null,"_labels":null,"name":"Umbria","uuid":"4fd434a4-1eb7-4177-9a0d-d1f5aa5efdaf"}}
]
```

now, I want to use it with React, but I cannot get rid of accessing it: it seems that React could manipulate only arrays of raw elements and not of complex objects.

I used

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

   React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/regions/2")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .then((data) => setData(data.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the console.log output is

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

and each element is like

```
0:{regions: {…}}
  regions:{_id: null, _labels: null, name: 'Lazio', uuid: 'ca1c1021-92f4-412b-aa3d-6c997cba248e'}
  _id:null
  _labels:null
  name:'Lazio'
  uuid:'ca1c1021-92f4-412b-aa3d-6c997cba248e'
  __proto__:Object
__proto__:Object
```

the result on the browser is:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data is undefined
App/</<
src/App.js:15

  12 | const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  13 | 
  14 |  React.useEffect(() => {
> 15 |   fetch("/regions/2")
     | ^  16 |     .then((res) => res.json())
  17 |     .then(data => console.log(data))
  18 |     .then((data) => setData(data.message));
```

So, my stupid question is: how can I unwrap objects using React?

All the examples on the net are simple and related to stupid arrays like [1,2,3,4,5] ...

Comment: It has nothing to do with React not being able to use complex objects (it can handle any level of complex object), the problem is you aren't returning from your second `then`, and this line `.then((data) => setData(data.message));` is throwing the error since `data` is undefined.

Comment: Remove this line: `.then(data => console.log(data))`.

Comment: After you remove that, you will begin getting an error here: `<p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>` since React won't know how you want to render an array of objects like that. But that will be a difficult question to answer without knowing what you want to do with `data`.

Comment: Along with what Brain Thompon has suggested you are not looping through data and returning an element through each loop to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are receiving an array of objects, you can use map function to iterate over it and display.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/regions/2")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setData(data.message); //or setData(data) depending the shape of the response
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          {!data
            ? "Loading..."
            : data.map((item) => <p key={item.regions.uuid}>{item.regions.name}</p>)}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you SuleymanSah. This definitely solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

With `setData(data)` it run!

My problem was definitely the following line, where I needed to define the key and to display the name

```
data.map((item) => <p key={item.regions.uuid}>{item.regions.name}</p>)
```